# XSLT Sheet Not Being Used

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Very next to XML, I've developed an XML sheet, alongside a XSD schema and finally a XSLT sheet to display the content. When I view the XML data sheet in a web browser (done in visual studio) it says the following:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

I've tried different filepaths and messed with the header, by not luck.

XML Data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xslt" href="lecturelayout.xslt"?>
<university>
<lesson>
  <subject>Biology</subject>
  <maintopic name="Human Biology">
    <subtopic>Enlarge Hearts</subtopic>
    <subtopic>Heart Valves</subtopic>
  </maintopic>
  <content>
    <sentance>Very long sentance one</sentance>
    <sentance>Very long sentance two</sentance>
    <sentance>Very long sentance three</sentance>
  </content>
</lesson>

  <lesson>
    <subject>Chemistry</subject>
    <maintopic name="Periodic Table">
      <subtopic>Enlarge Hearts</subtopic>
      <subtopic>Heart Valves</subtopic>
    </maintopic>
    <content>
      <sentance>Very long sentance one</sentance>
      <sentance>Very long sentance two</sentance>
      <sentance>Very long sentance three</sentance>
    </content>
  </lesson>
</university>
```

XSLT Sheet - Note might not be 100% correct, obviously can't test it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <html>
        <body>
          <h1>Professional Training Facilities</h1>
            <strong>University: </strong>
            <xsl:for-each select="university/lesson">          
            <xsl:value-of select="subject"/>
          <br/>
          <p>
            <strong>Main Topic: </strong>
            <xsl:value-of select="maintopic=name"/>
          </p>
          <br/>
          <p>
            <strong>Sub Topics: </strong>
            <xsl:for-each select="maintopic">
              <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="subtopic"/>
              </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </p>
          <p></p>
          <strong>Content:</strong>
          <xsl:for-each select="content">
            <p>
              <xsl:value-of select="sentance"/>
            </p>
          </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each> 
          <br/>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Help greatly appreciated, spent a while research this but just can't find any info on XSLT, unlike XSL.

EDIT: A mate just copied that on his machine(not that he programs) and gets the same result, could someone try it out please? :)

Comment: What browser are you using?  Chrome and some other browsers have very strict security settings and will not load correctly if you are loading the files from the `file:/` scheme. Try verifying in IE to help determine if it is a problem with your XML/XSLT, or how you are loading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to adjusting the Processing Instruction @type to `type="text/xsl"`, as suggested by @Matt Gibson, you need to adjust the match expression for your template.

Your template is set to match on every attribute and `node()` and is producing multiple `<html>` elements(invalid).

Adjust your template match to the root node:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Comment: Cheers, still didn't work after that. After trying other examples which produced the same result. I found it to be Google Chrome, works fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Your type attribute should be `text/xsl`, not `text/xslt`. Try

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="lecturelayout.xslt"?>
```

Comment: Cheers, tried that and just get a blank web page, inspecting the source just shows the xml data

Comment: Yes, that's because your stylesheet's broken; I was going for one problem at a time :) For this kind of processing, I'd normally suggest debugging using a "real" XSLT processor (command-line, or an IDE-style XML editor with XSL support), and then trying it in a browser once it's working. Also, bear in mind different browsers are more or less helpful when it comes to XSL errors; in my experience Firefox and Opera tend to be better.